# How can i fix this java.io.NotSerializableException: error in java?

Tags: java, serialization, notserializableexception

I'm quite new to java and unsure how to fix this `java.io.NotSerializableException` error.

I'm trying to use an add button on the GUI to add an object to an array list 
Then write that object to a file so I am able to read it back.

Here is the code I'm using for the `Branch` class which implement Java `Serializable`:

```java
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Branch implements Serializable{
    private String branch_name;
    private String branch_address;

    public Branch(String Bname, String Baddress) {
        this.branch_name = Bname;
        this.branch_address = Baddress;

        public String getbranch_name(){
            return branch_name;
        }

        public String getbranch_address(){
            return branch_address;
        }

        public void show_branch_details() {
            System.out.println( " The branch name is : " + getbranch_name()
                    + " branch address :"+ getbranch_address()
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the add button:

```java
ArrayList<Branch> BranchList = new ArrayList<Branch>();
JButton AddBranch = new JButton("ADD BRANCH");
AddBranch.setBounds(10, 35, 161, 23);
AddBranch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String Bname = branchNameField.getText();
        String Baddress = branchAddressField.getText();

        Branch A = new Branch(Bname, Baddress);

        BranchList.add(A);

        for (int i = 0; i < BranchList.size(); i++) {
            displayInfo.append(BranchList.get(i).getbranch_name() +);
        }
        System.out.println("The ArrayList has " + BranchList.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < BranchList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(BranchList.get(i).getbranch_name());
        }
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("branch.dat");
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            //oos.writeObject(BranchList);
            for (int b = 0; b < BranchList.size(); b++) {
                oos.writeObject(BranchList.get(b));
            }
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("branch.dat");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            //BranchList = (ArrayList<Branch>)ois.readObject();
            Branch obj = null;

            while ((obj = (Branch) ois.readObject()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Name:" + obj.getbranch_name() + ", Address:"
                        + obj.getbranch_address());
            }
            ois.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(" IOE ERROR");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("class ERROR");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you show us the output of the program and the complete stack trace?

Comment: Is this what you mean                                                                                                            The ArrayList has 1
Testing 
 IOE ERROR
java.io.NotSerializableException: Branch
 at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1185)

Comment: Can you try adding this line in your Branch class ? private static final long serialVersionUID = 4L;

Comment: Added that and unfortunately im still getting the same error

Comment: Rather than writing it to file in loop , can you simply do  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("branch.dat");
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(BranchList);
            oos.close(); fos.close();

Comment: Please include your `Branch` class... the thing you posted doesn't compile.

Comment: Check this link for reference : https://howtodoinjava.com/java/collections/arraylist/serialize-deserialize-arraylist/

Comment: The Branch class is at the top

Comment: That does not compile.. so clearly it's different from what you are using.

Comment: I tried the  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("branch.dat"); ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos); oos.writeObject(BranchList); oos.close(); fos.close(); before however it still didnt work which is why i then tried the loop instead. As you can see i commented that line out oos.writeObject(BranchList) as it didnt work in the beginning

Comment: I added the Branch class in answer . Please use that .

Comment: ok could you also tell me what you changed so i know for future use please

Comment: Did it work for you ?  You included everything in the constructor. The closing brackets were missing

Comment: No unfortunately im stil getting the same error. Im really at a loss as to what the problem is

Comment: Is there anything else i can try?

Comment: I added a running example . Please check and change according to your JButton event listener. This code in answer works fine

Comment: The issue is that im supposed to add to the array list through taking the input from the jtextfields and then putting them in an arrayList. The example you gave does it manually through  BranchList.add(A); BranchList.add(B); so the code im writing is in the action performed method for the add branch button, not the main method. would you know how to make adjustments to it to fit those requirements?

Comment: So basically i have a gui that takes the branch name and address. It is then supposed to  create an object in the array list, write it to the file so that it can be read if needed all when the add branch button is selected

Answer (score 1):

Please use this as Branch class :

```
        import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

    class Branch implements Serializable{

        private String branch_name;
        private String branch_address;

        public Branch(String Bname, String Baddress) {
            this.branch_name = Bname;
            this.branch_address = Baddress;
        }
            public String getbranch_name(){
                return branch_name;
            }

            public String getbranch_address(){
                return branch_address;
            }

            public void show_branch_details() {
                System.out.println( " The branch name is : " + getbranch_name()
                        + " branch address :"+ getbranch_address());
            }

        }

    public class Test {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

            Branch A= new Branch("TestA","Add_A");
            Branch B= new Branch("TestB","Add_B");

            ArrayList<Branch> BranchList = new ArrayList<>();
            BranchList.add(A);
            BranchList.add(B);

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("branch.dat");
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(BranchList);
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();

            ArrayList<Branch> OutputBranchList = new ArrayList<>();
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("branch.dat");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            OutputBranchList = (ArrayList) ois.readObject();

            for(Branch branch : OutputBranchList) {
                System.out.println(branch.getbranch_name()+" "+ branch.getbranch_address());
            }
            ois.close();
        }
    }
```